# Regular Expression to remove space ,comma ,space from a string in java?

Tags: java, regex

i Have a string s "hello,sa n.txt"

but i want the string s ="hellosan.txt" no comma,no space, no semicolon,should be there
How can i do this in java Using regular expression?

Comment: *"Regular Expression to remove space ,comma ,space from a string..?"*  You want the spaces AND the spaces removed?  Seems you need one to remove repetition repeatedly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Unless he means `" , "` `:/`

Answer (score 6):

```
String input = "hello,sa n.txt";
String clean = input.replaceAll("[, ;]", ""); // replace any of ", ;" with "nothing"
```

Comment: i have to use Pattern class so what will be the regular Expression?

Comment: What will be the Pattern i.e i am using Pattern.compile("");

Comment: Don't use `Pattern`, use `replaceAll()` as per my code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to replace ALL of the commas, semicolons and spaces in your string:

```
replaceAll("[,;\\s]", "");
```

Comment: how can i do this in Pattern class?

Comment: @SandeepSokhal, what do you want to achieve/test using the Pattern class?

Comment: I am using Pattern p=Pattern.compile("") so, what Regular Expression should be written between double Quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    System.out.println("hello,sa n.txt".replaceAll("[, ;]", ""));
```